# My initially defined functions will not be called when put in the main() function. Not too sure why but it will print the else statement

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
  def main():
      print_welcome()
      print("\n")
      get_choice()

      if get_choice == 1:
          addition_drill()
      elif get_choice == 2:
          multiplication_drill()
      else:
          print("Sorry I don't quite understand. Quitting now.")


  main()
```

When I run the program, it asks for user input (get_choice()) and when I put 1, it will send it straight to the else statement. All the functinos are defined prior to the main(), but I am not sure why the main() will not call the add and multi drills.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   What is ```get_choice()```?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Don't forget to search for an answer first, and if you post your question, always include a [mre]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to the code was what hiro protagonist posted.

```py
def main()
    print_welcome()
    print("\n")
    choice = get_choice();
    if choice == 1:
        addition_drill()
    elif choice == 2:
        multiplication_drill()
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand. Quitting now.")
    main()
```

Thank you all for your help, I am sure I will be back on here in the future